# How to plot a series of ggplots inside the loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a data set with the following columns: "Site" (15 locations), "Real_date" (date of sampling) and "SL_mm" (size of objects)
I want to make a graph with `geom_boxplot` for each site. And each site will have a boxplot for each date (dates are different for each sites)

```
num = unique(sub2008$Site)
library(ggplot2)
ls=list()
for (i in 1:length(num)){
  df = subset(sub2008, sub2008$Site == num[i])
  ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(real_date), SL_mm)) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(title = paste0(num[i], ' 2008'))
}
```

But no graph is plotted. I probably missed something. It works for `plot()` function when I use `par()`but not sure what to do with `ggplot` then (I know about `multiplot` function but no idea how to incorporate it into the loop)

Comment: It would probably be easier if you looked into faceting (see functions listed here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/). ie `ggplot(sub2008) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(real_date), SL_mm)) + facet_grid(.~ Site)` Also, when making ggplot inside loops, you need to `print()` the object explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub2008 <- data.frame(
  Site = c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","c"),
  real_date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  SL_sm = c(4,2,4,1,2,4,7,4,10)
)

num = unique(sub2008$Site)
ls=list()
for (i in 1:length(num)){
  df = subset(sub2008, sub2008$Site == num[i])
  plot <- ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(real_date), SL_sm)) +
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(title = paste0(num[i], ' 2008'))
  print(plot)
}
```

Within the loop, the plots will not print automatically.  You have to explicitly use the print method.

Also, the variable in your code is "SL_sm" though in your question, you referred to it as "SL_mm", so double check that you are referring to it consistently.

As suggested by the commenter, this is a good use case for faceting:

```
sub2008 <- data.frame(
  Site = c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","c"),
  real_date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  SL_sm = c(4,2,4,1,2,4,7,4,10)
)
plot1 <- ggplot(sub2008) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(real_date), SL_sm)) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = paste0(num[i], ' 2008')) +
  facet_grid(Site~.)
print(plot1)
plot2 <- ggplot(sub2008) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(real_date), SL_sm)) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = paste0(num[i], ' 2008')) +
  facet_grid(.~Site)
print(plot2)
```